# Redmine throughs error like "visibility is not included in the list" while clicking issues, gantt tabs

Tags: redmine

Redmine throughs error like "visibility is not included in the list" while clicking issues, gantt tabs. I'm getting confused while accessing redmine.

Can any one help?

[Redmine Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IPbg.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `Queue::visibility` field being `null` while rendering these pages. There are two probable reasons for this:

- The `visibility` field in `queues` database table not having default value, because of failed migrations or database transfer. To fix, use a query like:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE queues ALTER COLUMN visibility SET DEFAULT TO 0;
  ```
- Having null values in `queues` table, which can be fixed by:

  ```
  UPDATE queries SET visibility = 0 WHERE (visibility IS NULL);
  ```